# How to make the selected values in a dynamic drop down lists remain selected?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, selected

I have 5 drop down lists and a submit button. Every content of the drop down list is depend on the selection value of the previous drop down list. I would like to make sure that the selected value for the every drop down list remain selected even after the submit button is being clicked. Can anyone help me in this?
I saw a site that does that but was made in ASP.NET, i prefer tu use PHP, javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeSelect(lang, num, valueElement, nameSelect, nameSpan, dataSup, endId){
    var boxName =  document.getElementById(nameSelect);
    var hackIeSpan =  document.getElementById(nameSpan);
    var contentOption = $.ajax({
          url: "select.php",
          global: false,
          type: "POST",
          data: {
                 lang : lang,
                 num : num,
                 select : valueElement,
                 dataSup : dataSup,
                 endId : endId
             },
          dataType: "html",
          async:false,
          success: function(msg){
        }
       }
    ).responseText;
    hackIeSpan.innerHTML = contentOption;
}
```

```
<form id="searchForm" method="post" action="search.php?search&page=0&lang=<?php echo $lang; ?>">
            <fieldset>

                <select name="sort" onchange="changeSelect('<?php echo $lang; ?>', 1, this.value, 'type_list', 'hackIeType', 'null', 'null'); return true;">
                    <option value="0"><?php echo trad('SEARCH_01', $lang); ?></option>
                    <option value="Rental"><?php echo trad('SEARCH_01a', $lang); ?></option>
                    <option value="Sale"><?php echo trad('SEARCH_01b', $lang); ?></option>
                </select>

                <span id="hackIeType">
                    <select name="type_list">
                        <option value="0"><?php echo trad('SEARCH_04', $lang); ?> ...</option>
                    </select>
                </span>
```

.......

```
<span id="hackIeSleeps">
                    <select name="bedrooms">
                        <option value="0"><?php echo trad('SEARCH_05', $lang); ?> ...</option>
                    </select>
                </span>
                <span id="spanEndId">
                    <input id="endId" name="endId" type="hidden" value="" /> 
                </span>

                <input id="submit_search_home" type="submit" value="<?php echo trad('BTNSEARCH', $lang); ?>" />

            </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you press the submit button? Do you end up back on the same page? You just need to give the required option a `selected="selected"` attribute, based on the values sent in `$_POST`.

As an example (this may not work for you, depending on exactly what happens when you press submit):

```
<form id="searchForm" method="post" action="search.php?search&page=0&lang=<?php echo $lang; ?>">
  <fieldset>
    <select name="sort" onchange="changeSelect('<?php echo $lang; ?>', 1, this.value, 'type_list', 'hackIeType', 'null', 'null'); return true;">
      <option value="0"<?php if ($_POST['name'] === '0') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo trad('SEARCH_01', $lang); ?></option>
      <option value="Rental"<?php if ($_POST['name'] == 'Rental') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo trad('SEARCH_01a', $lang); ?></option>
      <option value="Sale"<?php if ($_POST['name'] == 'Sale') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo trad('SEARCH_01b', $lang); ?></option>
    </select>
    <span id="hackIeType">
<?php

  if ($_POST['name'] === '0') {
   // The first select value is default, so we can just output a standard select
   // to be populated by AJAX

?>
      <select name="type_list">
        <option value="0"><?php echo trad('SEARCH_04', $lang); ?> ...</option>
      </select>
<?php

  } else {
   // The first select is populated, so copy the logic that generates your second
   // select from 'select.php' and put it here, then output it
  }

?>
   </span>
```

.......

```
    <span id="hackIeSleeps">
<?php

  if ($_POST['type_list'] === '0') {
   // The second select value is default, so we can just output a standard select
   // to be populated by AJAX

?>
      <select name="bedrooms">
        <option value="0"><?php echo trad('SEARCH_05', $lang); ?> ...</option>
      </select>
<?php

  } else {
   // The second select is populated, so copy the logic that generates your third
   // select from 'select.php' and put it here, then output it
  }

?>
    </span>
    <span id="spanEndId">
      <input id="endId" name="endId" type="hidden" value="" /> 
    </span>
    <input id="submit_search_home" type="submit" value="<?php echo trad('BTNSEARCH', $lang); ?>" />
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: When i press submit button he send me to search.php?search&page=0&lang=uk, but you cand see that in action="search.php?search&page=0&lang=<?php echo $lang; ?>".

Comment: @user921130 Yes, but is it the same page as you have posted code from? In other words, is the HTML code you posted part of `search.php` or is it part of some other page?

Comment: The selected="selected" atribute works only for the first part when you select Rental or Sale, the second select have no option because you need to select with mouse (onchange="changeSelect(...)") the first selection to work the second one. See the first javascript code if you need i cand put some code frome select.php

Comment: No this is all the code from header.php, he uses select.php(you candsee that in first javascript code) and he send to search.php, there listed what i selected from dropdownmenu

Comment: Then you need to add a `window.onload` event (or whatever jQuery equivalent you want) which looks at the value of the first select when the page is loaded, and fires all the subsequent `changeSelect()` calls if the first select does not have the default value.

Comment: Every drop down list is depend on the selection value of the previous drop down list not only of the first selection

Comment: I do understand that, but I have just realised what your problem is. You would need to store all the submitted values in a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) and examine that session data within `select.php`. So your `onload` event will look at the value of the first select, if it is not default go and fetch the second select, `select.php` will look at the value in the session and add a `selected="selected"` as appropriate, then `onload` will look at the value of the second select... and so on and so on until you have populated all your selects.

Comment: To be honest, a far better approach would be to generate the subsequent selects within header.php as appropriate, that way there are no extra ajax calls. You can still keep your current system when the first select is default - but if it isn't, generate the next select(s) when the page is loaded.

Comment: I don't know how to do that but i will try :(. Thx for the answer

Comment: It should be fairly simple, you just need to copy some of the logic that generates your selects into `header.php`. See the update to my answer that will be posted in 2-3 minutes.

Comment: I don't understand and anyway i can move all the code from select.php in header.php. What you mean with (to be populated by AJAX).

Comment: When you change the value of a select, and AJAX call fetches the values for the next select, correct? Or have I mis-read the code entirely?

Comment: So why can't you just adapt the code from `select.php` to work, not from the data posted by AJAX, but from the data posted from the form submission, and put it into `header.php`?